# Subsonic 3 LeftOuterJoin

Tags: subsonic3, left-join

I have a problem. I want to create sql question

select * from Firma left outer join FirmaAdres on FirmaAdres.Typ = 1 and FirmaAdres.FirmaID = Firma.ID

in subsonic

I have written

SelectColumns("Firma.*").From().LeftOuterJoin(FirmaTable.IDColumn, FirmaAdresTable.FirmaIDColumn).And(FirmaAdresTable.AdresTypIDColumn).IsEqualTo(1)

When I checked what sql question is created I noticed then left outer join is changed to Inner join!!!

Could anyone help me??

Answer (score 0):

Subsonic doesn't support LeftOuterJoin.  You need to emulate the left join in LINQ (see http://www.devsource.com/c/a/Languages/Defining-a-Left-Join-with-LINQ-Queries/ for more details)  In my opinion the effort don't deserves the pain that is wating for you.  I suggest you to use a simple, boring and traditional stored procedure here.